# Put into map after recursive directory-scan

Tags: java, for-loop, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to programm a tool, which does replicate updated files into a folder structure. This folder structure is separated into "instances", so the root folder shows those:

- Test1 [Directory]
- Test2 [Directory]
- Test3 [Directory]

Within those directories, there are further directories and of course files. As I want to update a few files within those folders (the updated files are within another folder, where my tool has access to), I search the whole structures. The updated filenames are identical to those old, within Test1, Test2 and Test3, respectively their subfolders.

I looked up a recursive method to go through those folders and search. When my tool finds a second file within the same instance, it has to throw an error and end the for-loop.

In addition, after looking up for one update-file (patchfile), the temporary list, where I check if a duplicate exists, gets emptied. This all works fine, as in the code.

But by looking forward to the step where I want to replace the old file in the instances with the patchfile from the patchfolder, I get confused and don't know how to work.

I planned to map the place of the old (scanned) file (value in the map) and the actual patchfile (key) and just work over the elements within the map. **But where do I place the put-function perfectly?** Th**e nested loops within my main-methode (iterating over the instances and iterating over the many patchfiles) in addition to the recursive method of scanning on instance, makes me confused where to put the "map.put(...)".**

Here is my code so far. In addition, if you have advice in optimizing, I would be greatful to hear.

Further mentiones: My tool gets the parentfolder of the instances via an xml and JAXB and puts the list of instances, which are scanned into an ArrayList (instances -> getInstances())I iterate over.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, JAXBException {
    XMLHandler xmlhandler = new XMLHandler();
    InstanceManager manager = new InstanceManager();
    PatchFileManager patchManager = new PatchFileManager(xmlhandler.getUpdateFolder());

    patchManager.scanDirectoryForPatches();
    ArrayList<PatchFile> patchFilesname = patchManager.getPatchFiles();
    manager.setPathnameToScan(xmlhandler.getTargetFolder());
    manager.scanDirectoryForInstances(manager.getPathnameToScan());
    PatchManager ptchmngr = new PatchManager();

    outerloop:
    for (PatchFile f : patchFilesname) {
        for (Instance e : manager.getInstances()) {
            ptchmngr.scanInstallationForPatchFile(e.getPathname(), f);
            if(ptchmngr.getPatchSearchTempChecker().size()>1){
                System.out.println("loop stopped");
                break outerloop;
            }
        }

    }
....
}
}
```

And the actual class, where the scanning for the folders happens (getters- and setters excluded)

```
public class PatchManager {

private InstanceManager theInstanceManager;
private ArrayList<BackUp> backUpList = new ArrayList<BackUp>();
private ASPXManager theAspxHandler;
private ArrayList<PatchFile> patchFileList = new ArrayList<PatchFile>();
private LogManager theLogManager;
private ArrayList<String> patchSearchTempChecker = new ArrayList<String>();
private HashMap map = new HashMap();

public void copyPatch(PatchFile patchfile) {

}

public void searchFiles(PatchFile patchFile) {

}

public void createBackUp(PatchFile patchfile) {

}

public void scanInstallationForPatchFile(String searchstart, PatchFile patchfile) {
    File filetoSearch = new File(searchstart);
    try {
        if (filetoSearch.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Searching directory..." + filetoSearch.getAbsolutePath());
            if (filetoSearch.canRead()) {
                for (File temp : filetoSearch.listFiles()) {
                    if (patchSearchTempChecker.size() > 1) {
                        throw new DoubleDefinitionException();
                    }
                    if (temp.isDirectory() && !(temp.getName().equals("Images"))) {
                        scanInstallationForPatchFile(temp.getAbsolutePath(), patchfile);
                    } else {
                        if (patchfile.getFilename().toLowerCase().equals(temp.getName().toLowerCase())) {
                            patchSearchTempChecker.add(temp.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                            System.out.println(patchSearchTempChecker.size());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Permission denied");
        }
    } catch (

    DoubleDefinitionException ex)

    {
        System.out.println("File does exist multiple times within instance, proceed manually");
    }
}
//Getters and Setters
//...
//
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem? maybe I missed it, but could you highlight?

Comment: You want to take a batch of patch from one directory and apply it to another? Sounds like a job for git.

Comment: Nonetheless I want to programm this via Java. And pervertating a version control software does not seem very smart to me.